# true-false questions in exams R package

Tags: r-exams

I am trying to build a true-false question in exams R package. It is a single choice exercise with only two possible answers in the Answerlist. Here is the code:

```
Question
========
¿Puede una variable clasificarse como cualitativa continua?

Answerlist
----------
* Si
* No

Solution
========
No es posible ya que una variable continua debe ser nesezariamente una variable cuantitativa.

Answerlist
----------
* False
* True

Meta-information
================
exname: Escalas de medicion 01
extype: schoice
exsolution: 01
exshuffle: 2
```

After runing `exams2html(question.Rmd)` the output have three posible answers including `NA`

[image: output]

I am doing anything wrong?

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_CO.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_CO.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_CO.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_CO.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.0     purrr_0.3.4    
 [5] readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.1.0     tibble_3.0.3    ggplot2_3.3.2  
 [9] tidyverse_1.3.0 exams_2.3-6     pacman_0.5.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.4.6     compiler_4.0.2  
 [5] dbplyr_1.4.4     tools_4.0.2      jsonlite_1.7.0   lubridate_1.7.9 
 [9] lifecycle_0.2.0  gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.7     
[13] reprex_0.3.0     cli_2.0.2        rstudioapi_0.11  DBI_1.1.0       
[17] haven_2.3.1      withr_2.2.0      xml2_1.3.2       httr_1.4.2      
[21] fs_1.4.2         generics_0.0.2   vctrs_0.3.2      hms_0.5.3       
[25] grid_4.0.2       tidyselect_1.1.0 glue_1.4.1       R6_2.4.1        
[29] fansi_0.4.1      readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.8     blob_1.2.1      
[33] magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.8  scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.1  
[37] rvest_0.3.5      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1 stringi_1.4.6   
[41] munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.7.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this. For me `exshuffle: TRUE` and `exshuffle: 2` both work correctly. Which version of `exams` is this? I tried the devel version, the CRAN version, and version 2.3-0 (from 2017), all of which lead to the desired output. Maybe you had another `question.Rmd` in addition to the one you posted here?

Comment: I updated the post with my session info. version is ```exams_2.3-6```

Comment: Thanks for this, I detected and fixed the bug now. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the `exams` package that only occurred under certain circumstances. It has been fixed in version 2.4-0 of the package.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by setting the

```
exshuffle: TRUE
```